# Restcomm SMSC keeps raising ActivityAlreadyExistsException when submit_sm request is sent

Tags: java, jboss, smpp, restcomm, mobicents

I am using the latest version of Restcomm SMSC (smscgateway-7.3.153) (available here: https://github.com/RestComm/smscgateway/releases/tag/7.3.153). I used the binary version and not the source code.

I have got it up and running ad it communicates with Cassandra which is hosted on a different machine appropriately.

I have registered an ESME as a server and when I try to send a bind request, it succeeds and session is created. The problem occurs when I send the Submit_SM request. An ActivityAlreadyExists exception is raised and nothing else happens. I tried different simulators, even used an Android client to try to send a message but every time, the same exception occurs. I tried to debug the issue and was able to find out that the exception occurs when a new activity is about to be created but can't seem to find any more information.

It could be related to sequence numbers but I double checked and that doesn't seem to be the problem. I tried to change the tracing level of the server but I wasn't able to do so (Please guide me if anyone knows how to do it).

I am attaching a .pcap file that shows the packets I captured via Wireshark. All the request and response packets will be in there. I will also attach the server logs.

I couldn't find any help regarding this on the internet so if anyone of you can guide me here, I'd be very obliged. Please tag the developers if you know them. Feel free to ask for more information.

[Wireshark capture file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gkxPAd4Gi6mr21ZdaptDEvlAnFoV0o0E/view?usp=sharing)

These are the logs that are generated at the start of server:

[Server startup Logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mjhn6NrT_Jv71BMqBQC8i6ac1Bn07PU7/view?usp=sharing)

This is the exception logs' file:

[Exception logs file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MxqmIGC1lN6IthDP1kV2HmdpSGOFkuRH/view)

Here is the exception:

11:26:53,196 INFO  [SmppServerConnector] (SmppManagement) New channel from [192.168.1.173:34034]
11:26:53,215 INFO  [UnboundSmppSession] (SmppManagement.UnboundSession.192.168.1.173:34034) received PDU: (bind_transceiver: 0x00000025 0x00000009 0x00000000 0x00000001) (body: systemId [test5] password [test5] systemType [] interfaceVersion [0x34] addressRange (0x01 0x01 [6666])) (opts: )
11:26:53,215 INFO  [DefaultSmppServerHandler] (SmppManagement.UnboundSession.192.168.1.173:34034) Session created: Name=test5 SystemId=test5
11:26:55,504 ERROR [SmppSessionHandlerInterfaceImpl] (test5) Error while processing PduRequest=(submit_sm: 0x0000002F 0x00000004 0x00000000 0x00000002) (body: (serviceType [] sourceAddr [0x01 0x01 [6666]] destAddr [0x01 0x01 [5555]] esmCls [0x03] regDlvry [0x01] dcs [0x00] message [48656C6C6F21])) (opts: )
javax.slee.resource.ActivityAlreadyExistsException: RA:SmppServerRA:SmppTransactionHandle [smppSessionConfigurationName=test5, smppTransactionType=INCOMING, seqNumnber=2]
    at org.mobicents.slee.runtime.activity.ActivityContextFactoryImpl.createActivityContext(ActivityContextFactoryImpl.java:157)
    at org.mobicents.slee.runtime.activity.ActivityContextFactoryImpl.createActivityContext(ActivityContextFactoryImpl.java:57)
    at org.mobicents.slee.resource.SleeEndpointImpl._startActivity(SleeEndpointImpl.java:312)
    at org.mobicents.slee.resource.SleeEndpointStartActivityNotTransactedExecutor.execute(SleeEndpointStartActivityNotTransactedExecutor.java:63)
    at org.mobicents.slee.resource.SleeEndpointImpl.startActivity(SleeEndpointImpl.java:176)
    at org.restcomm.slee.resource.smpp.SmppServerResourceAdaptor.startNewSmppServerTransactionActivity(SmppServerResourceAdaptor.java:277)
    at org.restcomm.slee.resource.smpp.SmppSessionsImpl$SmppSessionHandlerImpl.firePduRequestReceived(SmppSessionsImpl.java:236)
    at com.cloudhopper.smpp.impl.DefaultSmppSession.firePduReceived(DefaultSmppSession.java:606)
    at com.cloudhopper.smpp.channel.SmppSessionWrapper.messageReceived(SmppSessionWrapper.java:52)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at com.cloudhopper.smpp.channel.SmppSessionLogger.handleUpstream(SmppSessionLogger.java:104)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at com.cloudhopper.smpp.channel.SmppSessionThreadRenamer.handleUpstream(SmppSessionThreadRenamer.java:59)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:124)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)